# How to Auto Login into third party site by passing the username and password from hidden fields

Tags: javascript, html

Following code is working when I am passing a correct session ID to the viewstate. but not working without session ID. Is it possible what I am trying.

What I have tried is:---

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
</head>
<body >             
<form id="login" name="login" method="post" action="http://thirdPartySite/jsf/security/login.jsp" >
<input type="hidden" name="login" value="login">
                    <div >
                        <input id="userName" type="hidden" name="userName" autocomplete="off" value="yyyyy">
                    </div>
                    <div >
                        <input id="password" type="hidden" name="password" autocomplete="off" value="xxxx"  >
                    </div>
                    <div >
                        <input type="submit" name="j_id_jsp_623365074_6" value="Login" ><br>                   

                    </div>
                <input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="javax.faces.ViewState" value="712612493959427831:-20824210214191552" autocomplete="off">
</form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body></html>
```

Comment: How did you find the session ID from third party site ?Also when you found, how do you match that session ID? The third party should have its own sessions on the server end.

Comment: In above code the last field containing the value if am trying to put wrong value or making this null the site says session expired.   <input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="javax.faces.ViewState" value="712612493959427831:-20824210214191552" autocomplete="off">

Comment: Yes, i can see that, but question is, how're you getting this session ID? The session values are stored on server end, same on the third party. How do you match these values?

Comment: I just coping from the element by inspect third party site. So its stored on locally.

Comment: This seems some hacking trick. But basically you cannot do this by this way, the reason is, the session IDs generate different every time against each user. Therefore, simply if there is no match for the session ID, the system won't run.